# Using Namespaces but not for default classes

Tags: php, namespaces

Since yesterday I am going to use namespaces in php and I have a little problem there:

```
namespace NamespaceName;

use StdClass;

$s = new StdClass;
$s->meow = "Hello World";

echo $s->meow;
```

Is there any way that I must not include the "use StdClass"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to put a backspace in your declaration, so that you use StdClass from the global namespace:

```
 $s = new \StdClass;
        //^ See here
```